# Generate Firebase User Token in Bash or Python

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Raspberry Pi and want to send data from it to my Firebase database.
To do this, I created an user account with email and password in my database and I store them on the Pi.

*The problem/idea:*

1. I take a measurement and want to send the data to my database using the specific user account.
2. **I get a token for the credentials (email&password) in Bash or Python.**
3. I use the token to send the data, e.g. using the REST API.
4. I do not want to store the admin/service account secret on the Pi.

How could I achieve this? I did not find any way to get the user token in Bash/Python without the account secret.

Comment: [Rest Sign-in with Email/Password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password).  Please note you need to start the authentication as described near the top of the page I linked.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.